Does checking updated_at field helps in caching?
I participated in technical interview with mobile developer (flutter). I asked about caching products (in ecommerce project). He says a strategy that initially he fetches all products (let's say we have pagination also). After that in every re-fetch he compares updated_at field of products with incoming request products. If any of them changed he re-fetches if not he gets from cache. I heard about this for the first time. What are pros and cons of this? Is it a best practice?
